# XML format error on Roumen Damianoff laravel-sitemap

Tags: xml, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to develope an xml sitemap for a laravel 4.2 website with laravel-sitemap 2.4.16 by Roumen Damianoff but the xml rendered is not valid and is not being shown properly in most browsers.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9  http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<url>
<loc>http://localhost/vinas/public</loc>
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://localhost/vinas/public/es/inicio" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://localhost/vinas/public/en/home" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="http://localhost/vinas/public/fr/home" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="pt" href="http://localhost/vinas/public/pt/home" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ca" href="http://localhost/vinas/public/ca/inici" />
    <priority>1.0</priority>
    <lastmod>2015-07-08T11:03:08+02:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>
</urlset>
```

That happens if I try to add translations to the sitemap, if I don't, everything works fine. The xml validation error  is as follows...

> The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for
>   element 'xhtml:link'.

How can I fix this xml? Or... is everything ok and even if the xml does not render properly on some browsers the crawlers are going to make use of it nicely?

Answer (score 0):

Change order like below

```
  <url>
    <loc>http://localhost/vinas/public</loc>
    <lastmod>2015-07-08T11:03:08+02:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>

    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://localhost/vinas/public/es/inicio" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://localhost/vinas/public/en/home" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="http://localhost/vinas/public/fr/home" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="pt" href="http://localhost/vinas/public/pt/home" />
    <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="ca" href="http://localhost/vinas/public/ca/inici" />
  </url>
```

Comment: Hi, it still did not validate on http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/ and the xml did not render either on the browser. However, I realized that if I try to validate de xml (with or without the change of order suggested) at http://www.validome.org/google/validate it passes the validation smoothly.